# How can I implement auto search on multiple fields using completion sugesstor, and is there a way to auto map multiple field value to completion field

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, nest

I have been struggling to find a way to implement elastic search auto complete.
My requirement is like this, In my index I have fields a,b,c,d

I want to show the top 5 search suggestion in the order
(a,b,c)
d

I am using Nest 7.17,
I tried using multi match query, term suggest but none of them work as I want

So I read about completion suggestion and how I can add weight to the input but currently I am struggling with 2 things

1. I want to have a completion field which have multiple field value in it
2. I am trying to find a way to auto add it in index

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: I want to have a completion field which have multiple field value in
it?

Answer: You can assign multiple values as array
field = [ "Alphabet Inc", "Google", "Youtube", "Playstore"]

Question 2: I am trying to find a way to auto add it in index?
Answer: There is only one weight field to increase relevance/score. You need to create a function, either you need to create a formula for example a, b, c, d.

```
if a:
  weight = 4
if b:
  weight = 3
if c:
  weight = 2
if d:
  weight = 1
```

This article might be helpful for you.
https://taranjeet.medium.com/elasticsearch-using-completion-suggester-to-build-autocomplete-e9c120cf6d87